# Listing jndi datasources configured in the context.xml Tomcat via code

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8

Does Tomcat8 provide some API or is it possible, via code, to get the list of all the JNDI datasources configured in the `context.xml` file ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to get the JNDI names:

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NameClassPair;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import java.util.*;

try {
    Context context = new InitialContext();

    NamingEnumeration enm = context.list("java:comp/env/jdbc");

    while (enm.hasMore()) {
        NameClassPair b = (NameClassPair) enm.next();
        System.out.println( b.getName() );
    }

} catch (NamingException ne) {
    //
}
```